# morphing with anime.js: coordinates jump somewhere else in between given start and end position

Tags: javascript, css, svg, anime.js

I have two `svg` triangles and I am trying to morph them with `anime.js`. The problem that I have is that in between the given start and end coordinates the graphic jumps completely somewhere else and I don't know why.

This is the start position:

[image]

This is the end position:

[image]

And this is where the coordinates jump to without a knowing reason:

[image]

Here is my example code. You can start it by clicking the button.

https://codepen.io/saitam1/pen/draKLb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from your paths.

For the animation not to brutally change the position of the triangles, the path must use relative coordinates `m` when your first path is using absolute coordinates `M`.

Changing from `m` to `M` fixes the triangle jumping but you have to find another path to actually get to the desired final position.

```js
function doFunction() {

  var paths = [
    // here changed M to m
    {id: '#path309', d: 'm 55.184523,127.42857 34.962798,139.6183 43.46726,120.24702 Z'}, 
    {id: '#path311', d: 'm 54.389347,121.02185 -10.922087,-0.77483 11.717263,7.18155 z'}
  ];

  var timeline = anime.timeline({ autoplay: true, direction: 'alternate', loop: false });

  paths.forEach(function(path, index) {
    timeline
      .add({
        targets: path.id,
        d: {
          value: path.d,
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        },
        offset: 1000 + 10 * index
      });
  });

}
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doFunction();" />  

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100mm" height="100mm" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      
  <path d="m 110.51595,80.797791 26.28083,12.271789 2.96257,10.935445 z" id="path309" />
  <path d="m 70.51595,80.797791 -5.00762,25.058566 11.28845,-2.786777 z" id="path311" />
      
</svg>
```